# Print the indices of elements in one list according to the values of another list in seperate lines and print -1 for missing elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indices

```
A = [['a'],['a'],['b'],['c'],['b'],['a']]

B = [['k'],['k'],['a'],['b'],['k']]
```

I have two list, A and B.I have to print those elements index number(index number + 1) separated by space of list A,which elements also exist in list B.For every element of list B,i want to print the indices of the values in list A sequentially in one line.If there is any element of list B,that missing in list A, then i want to print -1 for this element.How can i fix this?

my code:

```
dict_B = dict([(b[0],[]) for b in B])

for i,a in enumerate(A):
    if a[0] in dict_B:
        dict_B[a[0]].append(i+1)

for key in dict_B:
    if dict_B[key] == []:
        c = 0
        for i,x in enumerate(B):
            if x == list(key):
                c += 1
        for x in range(c):
            if x == c-1:
                print(-1,end=" ")
            else:
                print(-1)
    else:
        for elem in dict_B[key]:
            print(elem,end=' ')
    print()
```

Output of my code:

```
-1
-1
-1 
1 2 6 
3 5
```

Expected Output:

```
-1
-1
1 2 6
3 5
-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here.

```
from collections import defaultdict
idx_dict=defaultdict(list)

for idx,[val] in enumerate(A,1):
    idx_dict[val].append(idx)

for [key] in B:
    if key in idx_dict:
        print(' '.join(map(str,idx_dict[key])))
    else:
        print(-1)
```

Output:

```
-1
-1
1 2 6
3 5
-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're over complicating the problem, I'm not sure why you need to use a `dict`.

```py
for item_b in B:
    found = []
    for i, item_a in enumerate(A):
        if item_a == item_b:
            found.append(str(i + 1))
    print(" ".join(found) or -1)
```

Output:

```
-1
-1
1 2 6
3 5
-1
```